# Draw multiple shapes from csv file in processing

Tags: java, processing

I'm new to Processing, and I want to make X number of ellipses. I'll get that number from a csv file. Is there any option to make multiple ellipses?

Comment: Also, can you add a few lines of the csv files ? (what does the data look like) ? Check out the [loadTable()](https://processing.org/reference/loadTable_.html) reference, it may help. Start by first loading and listing the data, then accessing the values you need, converting the Strings to numbers and drawing ellipses. One step at a time :)

Comment: it's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit ambiguous, especially this part:

> I'll get that number from a csv file.

Are you reading the coordinates of each ellipse from a csv file (the number of rows being the number of ellipses drawn) or you simply reading a single integer value `X` which represents the number of ellipses you need to draw (regardless of their position/size/etc. ?)

Let's start with the most basic part: drawing ellipses.
This is achieved using the [ellipse()](https://processing.org/reference/ellipse_.html) function which requires 4 parameters:

1. x position
2. y position
3. width
4. height

e.g. drawing a 20x20 pixels ellipse at coordinates 10,10:

```
ellipse(10,10,20,20);
```

In terms of reading a CSV file, as I've mentioned in the comment, the [loadTable()](https://processing.org/reference/loadTable_.html) function will help with that. The reference page actually includes an example of how to traverse each row and extract values.

Here is a basic example of how to draw ellipses based on x,y values present in a csv file. It loads a csv file, then loops through each row. For each row it accesses the first and second value. Notice the indexing starts at 0, not at 1.

```
Table table;

void setup(){
  //load the csv file
  table = loadTable("data.csv");
  //loop through each row
  for (TableRow row : table.rows()) {
    //extract the first and second value from the current row
    float x = row.getFloat(0);//extract the first value on the row, at index 0
    float y = row.getFloat(1);//extract the second value on the row, at index 1
    //use the current x,y values to draw an ellipse
    ellipse(x,y,5,5);
  }
}
```

and here is the sample data.csv file:

```
10,10
20,20
50,50
90,90
```

[image: sample file: ellipses drawn from csv data]

You can do quite a few fancy things with the [Table class](https://processing.org/reference/Table.html) like adding headers, which will allow you to get the values by their labels, rather than by index.

If you're simply reading a value X and you draw ellipses based on different parameters, you simply need to use a [for loop](https://processing.org/reference/for.html).
If you used programming basics like this, they're easy as 1,2,3:

1. declaring and initializing a variable
2. using a condition
3. accessing and modifying an existing variable

You can imagine them as a code structure that allows you to count from A to B.
Let's say you're counting 10 steps. A for loop will have 3 requirements:

1. a number with an initial value
2. a condition (to know when to stop)
3. an increment: how fast is the number changing from the initial to the final value

The syntax roughly looks like this (with the 3 requirements separated by `;`):

```
for (initial value ; condition ; incrementation){
   //instructions to repeat while condition is true
}
```

For example:

```
for (int step = 0; step < 10; step = step+1) {
  println("step " + step);
}
```

At this point you can skip steps (hop):

```
for (int step = 0; step < 10; step = step+2) {
  println("step " + step);
}
```

or even walk/count backwards:

```
for (int step = 10; step > 0; step = step-1) {
  println("step " + step);
}
```

This then can be easily applied to drawing x number of ellipses:

```
int x = 30;//assuming this value can be easily read
for (int ellipseCount = 0; ellipseCount < x; ellipseCount = ellipseCount+1) {
  float size = random(10);
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),size,size);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Please vote and/or tick the answer if it was helpful. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a basic **for loop**:

```
int ellipseCount = 10; //get this from csv file
size(500, 500);
background(0);
for (int i = 0; i < ellipseCount; i++) {
  ellipse(random(width), random(height), 10, 10);
}
```